# How to set headers on native browser requests, or otherwise provide authorization headers while using Video.js to play video from Microsoft Azure?

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, video.js, request-headers

I am trying to load some video content from Microsoft Azure, using Video.js, and I need to add some headers for SharedKey authorization. I have been trying various methods and doing research for several days, but I am hitting brick walls and could really use some assistance.

Important to note that this is for a mobile app written using Angular / Cordova.

This is how Azure suggests that we do it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/player-how-to-video-js-player

Basically, by attaching a function to videojs.Hls.xhr.beforeRequest.

Unfortunately, there are several problems with this approach. Here is a ticket in the videojs issue tracker trying to look for a solution to these issues:

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/7207

In summary:

1- We are not using HLS/DASH. We are loading mp4 files from blob storage. And videojs "hands that off directly to the browser, and it handles all loading of things while not providing this extra set of functionality."

2- Even if we were to convert the media and use HLS, "this method won't be available because native playback is used for Safari with HLS.". (So do we need to use DASH? Or does that not work on Safari either?)

3- There is still no way to add headers for Subtitle tracks, whether we use native subtitles, or add them through videojs.players.video.addRemoteTextTrack.

I have also tried other alternative methods like

1- Trying to use xhook to intercept it.

2- Trying to use @angular/common/http/HttpInterceptor.

Neither method worked.

So, my questions would be:

1- Is there a method I'm overlooking that would allow me to add / inject headers to requests being made natively by the browser?

2- Could it perhaps be done with an authorization cookie? I have seen this mentioned in some other questions, but I couldn't find any concrete examples, and I'm not sure how it would work with Azure.

3- If all else fails, is there another video player I could use that does provide better support in regards to authorization options?

Any other suggestions would be also be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you're streaming directly from blob storage, can you not create a shared access signature URL on the blob and use that in your video player?

Comment: That... is actually a really good suggestion. I'm not quite sure if I completely understand how it works. I think I need to use a User Delegation SAS, and generate the SAS token on the app side, using the account key, and add it to the URL? So these tokens are like single-use? For example if I'm using a token to access a file like https://blob.azure.com/file.txt?token=2cn9ry3ryn , then could someone copy this URL and keep accessing the file using the same token?

Comment: I was actually thinking of Service SAS token where you get the SAS token on the blob with Read permission for a limited amount of time. Once the SAS token expires, it can't be used by anybody else. You can further restrict the SAS by IP address. But I am guessing that User Delegation SAS can also be used.

Comment: I see. Can this "getting the SAS token for a limited amount of time" actually be done by the app, client side? Or are you suggesting that I only share the video for a set amount of time, then periodically change the token, and update the URL on the client to reflect that?

Comment: SAS URL should only be generated from server side (I am assuming that's your app). So basically every time a user requests a video, you first send a request to your API which will generate a SAS URL and send it back to the client. Your client will set the video URL as this SAS URL. HTH.

Comment: Okay, that really helps, thanks. The "app" is actually a hybrid mobile app written in angular (and cordova). But it does also have a server backend as well that I could use to generate the SAS URL if that would be necessary. But I think a hybrid app also technically counts as a "server" as far as this method is concerned? (Edit: I guess it's better to generate the token using php in order to not expose the account key.) Any chance you happen to have an example for SAS token generation? All I can find are methods to generate it using the Azure Portal, or through powershell.

Comment: Are you using PHP in your server-side backend?

Comment: Yep, I am using PHP on the server side. I found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472643/microsoft-azure-and-sas-for-php  which I think has some good answers that I will look into. Thanks for the help! If you can submit the SAS url as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Yeah, I think the link you mentioned can help. You can also use Azure Storage SDK for PHP as well. See this link: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/5dc75923f11042bca5b3cb6a16c82f3d104002cd/samples/BlobSamples.php#L373 for sample code. HTH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you're serving a video file stored as a blob in Azure Storage directly, you can make use of `Shared Access Signature (SAS)`. A SAS provides a time-limited, permission-bound access to a blob.

The way it would work is when a user requests a video to be played, you will need to send a request to your backend service. Your backend service will create a SAS token for the blob with `Read` permission (only this permission is required to play the video) and some expiry date (depending on the length of the video). Your backend service will return the SAS URL for the blob (which would be something like `blob-url?sas-token`) which will be used by the video player to play the video.

You can find more information about Shared Access Signature here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature. You will need to create a [`Service SAS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas) for your blob.